# How to get selected value in dependent dropdown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dependent dropdown and I'm using the get API to read and retrieve the selection option
With the current code I'm not able to show the selected value for the selection

I have 2 select function one is `State` and another one is `District`. District is dependent to State. Based on the value on the state it will display list of district.
With the current code the it's not selecting the current value of the district even thought the district already have value. it just that it did not showed up as `selected` how do I fix this code ?

This is what I have tried

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#state").change(function() {
        let stateID = $(this).val();
        getDist(stateID);
      });
    });

    const getDist = (state) => {
      axios.get(`${url}district?id=${state}`)
        .then(function(res) {
          if (res.data.status == 'success') {
            res.data.result.map((e) => {
              $('#dist').append(`<option value="${e.dist_id}" >${e.dist_name}</option>`);
            });
          }
        });
    }

    function getState() {
      return axios.get(`${url}state`);
    }

    Promise.all([getState(), getDetails(student)])
      .then(function(results) {
        const state = results[0];
        const student = results[1];

        if (state.data.status == 'success') {
          state.data.result.map((e) => {
            $('#state').append(`<option value="${e.st_id}">${e.st_name}</option>`);
          });
        }

        if (student.data.status == 'success') {
          let studData = student.data.result;
          $("#state").val(studData.state_id).change();
          $("#dist").val(studData.district_id).change();
        }
      });


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <select class="form-control mb-3" id="state">
          <option value="" hidden>Select State</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>District</label>
        <select class="form-control mb-3" id="dist">
          <option value="" hidden>Select District</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's an "independent dropdown"?  Do you mean "dependent"?  Can you narrow down where the error is?  ie which part of the code is the problem?  The ajax?  Adding elements? 
 Can you add new items with `$(() => $('#state').append('<option value="val">test</option>'));`?  What's the value of `state.data.result`?  Does it work if you hardcode a result (and skip the ajax)?

Comment: Also: Your question doesn't appear to be related to the title.  How to get selected value vs se

Comment: See [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal* to be able to *demonstrate* the issue.